# Outlook pst auto restoring

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

Good day.

I'm trying to copy a pst file from a desktop to a laptop. Outlook is configured the same on both machines.  Same pop3 account etc. The desktop pst is more up to date and want to get the laptop also up to date to use for travelling. After copying the pst, as soon as I execute Outlook the pst reverts back to what is was before the copy. The size of the file changes and the content.
What can cause this? Is it an outlook setting or a Windows 7 file restore feature?

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of just copying it over, perhaps export the mail to a .pst and import it into the laptop, skipping duplicates?

Comment: It's a big pst. About 6.9Gb. This is the requirement of a client of mine. I'm trying to automate the syncing for him. And thanx for the idea but I want to know what's causing the auto restoring.